# In bash, how to combine the output of two commands and append them on the SAME line of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, append

For example I have two commands here:

```
{ command1 & command2; } >> file1
```

For example the output of `command1` is `400`, and the output of `command2` is `4`.

So this is what I get:

```
400
4
```

I want the outputs of the two commands to be appended on the **same** line like this:

```
400 4
```

Comment: Are you sure you're going to get that output? You put command1 into the background, so how do you know you're guaranteed to get its output first?

Answer (score 2):

Your command basically is this.

```
$ (echo '400'  && echo '4') | hexdump -C
00000000  34 30 30 0a 34 0a                                 |400.4.|
00000006
```

Not the output includes the end of line `\n` aka `0a` characters.  So one easy thing you could do is pipe that through a command that will delete the `\n`.

So something like this

```
$ (echo '400'  && echo '4') | tr '\n' ' ' | hexdump -C
00000000  34 30 30 20 34 20                                 |400 4 |
00000006
```

Which has actual output of `400 4`.  But that doesn't include any line endings so you may want to only remove the line ending from the first command.

```
$ (echo '400' | tr '\n' ' ' && echo '4') | hexdump -C
00000000  34 30 30 20 34 0a                                 |400 4.|
00000006
```

Anyway, the point is that the line ending is just a character use tr, sed, awk, or your favorite tool that lets you do manipulation of the string.

One other option that may work, depending on your requirements may be to do something like below. With this, the output of the commands are magically stripped of the EOL for you, but an EOL is appended by the echo command.

```
$ echo "$(echo '400') $(echo '4')" | hexdump -C
00000000  34 30 30 20 34 0a                                 |400 4.|
00000006
```

Comment: I do not want to echo "400" The 400 is just a placeholder for the output of a command.

Comment: I know, replace the 'echo 400' with your command.  I was using that as an example.  Echo was just a useful **command** that would let me quickly make examples that gave results that exactly matched what you had in your question.

Comment: There's also: `paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2) >> file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `paste`

```
{ command1 & command2; } | paste -d" " -s >> file1
```

(concern about backgrounding command1 has been noted)

Demo:

```
$ { echo 400; echo 4; }
400
4
$ { echo 400; echo 4; } | paste -d" " -s
400 4
```